# Align text to the left in v-expansion-panel-header

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to align the text in my v-expansion-panel-headers but I don't know how to do it. I= have tried putting 'justify-self-start' class but it didn't change anything. It still looks like this:

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<v-expansion-panels class="hidden-xl-only" id="dimensions-caisse" background-color="transparent" style="maxWidth: 300px;">
                <v-expansion-panel id="margin-dimensions-ep">
                    <v-expansion-panel-header class="justify-self-start">
                        <v-icon>{{ icons.mdiResize }}</v-icon> Dimensions
                    </v-expansion-panel-header>
                    <v-expansion-panel-content>
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                                <v-text-field type="number" label="Longueur (mm)" v-model="vmodel.longueur"></v-text-field><v-text-field type="number" label="Largeur(mm)" v-model="vmodel.largeur"></v-text-field><v-text-field type="number" label="Hauteur (mm)" v-model="vmodel.hauteur"></v-text-field>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-expansion-panel-content>
                </v-expansion-panel>
                <v-expansion-panel id="margin-dimensions-ep">
                    <v-expansion-panel-header class="justify-self-start">
                        <v-icon>{{ icons.mdiTagOutline }}</v-icon> Etiquette
                    </v-expansion-panel-header>
                    <v-expansion-panel-content>
                        <v-radio-group v-model="vmodel.radioGroupLabel">
                            <v-radio label="Sur la longueur" value="labelLongueur"></v-radio>
                            <v-radio label="Sur la largeur" value="labelLargeur"></v-radio>
                            <v-radio label="Pas d'étiquette" value="noLabel"></v-radio>
                        </v-radio-group>
                    </v-expansion-panel-content>
                </v-expansion-panel>
                <v-expansion-panel id="margin-dimensions-ep">
                    <v-expansion-panel-header class="justify-self-start">
                        <v-icon>{{ icons.mdiWeight }}</v-icon> Poids de la caisse (kg)
                    </v-expansion-panel-header>
                    <v-expansion-panel-content>
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                                <v-text-field type="number" label="Poids" v-model="vmodel.poids"></v-text-field>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-expansion-panel-content>
                    <v-btn id="validCaissesep"  color="lightblue" class="white--text justify-center" @click="setDimensionsBox" :height="50"><v-icon color="white">{{ icons.mdiCheck }}</v-icon> Valider</v-btn>
                    <v-snackbar v-model="vmodel.snackbar" :timeout="2000">Données enregistrées.</v-snackbar>
                </v-expansion-panel>
            </v-expansion-panels>
```

Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Could you provide CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `v-expansion-header` should only contain a single root element, so you could wrap the icon and text in an element such as a `div`:

```html
<v-expansion-panel-header>
  <div>
    <v-icon>{{ icons.mdiTagOutline }}</v-icon> Etiquette
  </div>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vYmoNaL?editors=10100)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to align the icons and the texts. It is not all pushed to the left but I'm ok with what I have now:

[image]

I have added a v-container, a v-layout and a v-flex for each header like this:

```
<v-expansion-panels class="hidden-xl-only" id="dimensions-caisse" background-color="transparent" style="maxWidth: 300px;">
                <v-expansion-panel id="margin-dimensions-ep">
                    <v-expansion-panel-header class="justify-self-start">
                        <v-container>
                            <v-layout row>
                                <v-flex cols1><v-icon>{{icons.mdiResize}}</v-icon> </v-flex><v-flex cols11> Dimensions</v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-expansion-panel-header>
                    <v-expansion-panel-content>
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                                <v-text-field type="number" label="Longueur (mm)" v-model="vmodel.longueur"></v-text-field><v-text-field type="number" label="Largeur(mm)" v-model="vmodel.largeur"></v-text-field><v-text-field type="number" label="Hauteur (mm)" v-model="vmodel.hauteur"></v-text-field>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-expansion-panel-content>
                </v-expansion-panel>
                <v-expansion-panel id="margin-dimensions-ep">
                    <v-expansion-panel-header class="justify-self-start">
                        <v-container>
                            <v-layout row>
                                <v-flex cols1><v-icon>{{icons.mdiTagOutline}}</v-icon> </v-flex><v-flex cols11> Etiquette</v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-expansion-panel-header>
                    <v-expansion-panel-content>
                        <v-radio-group v-model="vmodel.radioGroupLabel">
                            <v-radio label="Sur la longueur" value="labelLongueur"></v-radio>
                            <v-radio label="Sur la largeur" value="labelLargeur"></v-radio>
                            <v-radio label="Pas d'étiquette" value="noLabel"></v-radio>
                        </v-radio-group>
                    </v-expansion-panel-content>
                </v-expansion-panel>
                <v-expansion-panel id="margin-dimensions-ep">
                    <v-expansion-panel-header class="justify-self-start">
                        <v-container>
                            <v-layout row>
                                <v-flex cols1><v-icon>{{icons.mdiWeight}}</v-icon> </v-flex><v-flex cols11> Poids de la caisse (kg)</v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-expansion-panel-header>
                    <v-expansion-panel-content>
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                                <v-text-field type="number" label="Poids" v-model="vmodel.poids"></v-text-field>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-row>
                    </v-expansion-panel-content>
```

Comment: You could simply wrap `v-expansion-header` content in a div. no need for container, row, col.